# ScriptFailed error in AfterInstall during CodeDeploy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, discord, aws-code-deploy

My python code runs properly in my machine, but its giving an error during CodeDeploy. The error in line 28, uses discord module which needs to be installed from requirements.txt

RunMyBot.sh

```
#!bin/bash

cd /home/dictionary_discordbot/
yum install -y python3-pip python3 python3-setuptools
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python dictionaryMain.py
```

appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/dictionary_discordbot
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/RunMyBot.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

User data in Instance

```
serverfile="/lib/systemd/system/mypythonservice.service"
echo "[Unit]" > $serverfile
echo "Description=My Python Service" > $serverfile
echo "After=multi-user.target" >> $serverfile

echo "[Service]" >> $serverfile
echo "Type=idle" >> $serverfile
echo "ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/dictionary_discordbot/dictionaryMain.py" >> $serverfile
echo "Restart=on-failure" >> $serverfile

echo "[Install]" >> $serverfile
echo "WantedBy=multi-user.target" >> $serverfile
cat $serverfile

sudo chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/mypythonservice.service

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl enable mypythonservice.service
```

[image]

Comment: are you confident that async is supported on python version your instance is using?

Comment: @Marcin I just remove the last line in RunMyBot.sh. The code has deployed successfully. But, why is my bot not up and running on discord?

Comment: @Marcin I added the last line again with python3, my bot was up temporarily while CodeDeploy was running. The CodeDeploy has Failed because of timeout. I want my bot to be running 24/7.